# Зачем нужен WebView в андроид?

Tags: android, android-webview

Не могу понять зачем нужен WebView, если по факту это просто сайт внутри приложения. Почему нельзя просто использовать браузер для просмотра сайта?

Answer (score 2):

Приложение имеет расширенный доступ к содержимому `WebView`, в отличие от браузера, который в целях безопасности подобный доступ полностью запрещает.

Соответственно, на базе `WebView` можно строить систему плагинов, чтобы веб страница имела доступ к коду приложения, так и просто динамически инжектить javascript, подставлять и изменять куки и прочее.

Также часто необходимо, чтобы пользователь не уходил из приложения во внешний браузер, чтобы навигация была полностью под контролем приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать браузер, если вы хотите ограничится просмотром сайта, но представьте ситуацию, когда у вас внутри приложения есть например oauth или платежная система, которая открывает окно с авторизацией с сайта банка итд итп.

Вообщем в приложении иногда есть необходимость показать веб-контент, не обязательно он должен быт скачан с сайта.

Так же есть приложения которые целиком и полностью сделаны под веб, но обернуты в webview, просто для скорости разработки под различные платформы. (любое приложение типа алиэкспресс)

Мало того. есть целые [фреймворки](https://ionicframework.com/), которые это делают под все мобильные платформы сразу и именно таким образом(через рендеринг веб контента)

UPD: Да, стоило упомянуть, компонент VebView не имеет встроенных ограничений, как браузер, и находится под полным вашим контролем.